# Cómo puedo traer datos de una base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo el código para insertar datos en la tabla pero no se cómo obtenerlos y poder mostrarlos en la página web, qué debo agregarle para obtener los 3 datos ingresados?

```js
<?php
    
    $db="";

$user="";

$server="";

$pass="";

$conecta=mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);

                   mysql_select_db($db,$conecta);

 $asunto =$_POST['asunto'];
 $correo =$_POST['correo'];
 $mensaje =$_POST['mensaje'];

  $insertar = "INSERT INTO tablat VALUES('$asunto', '$correo', '$mensaje')";

  $sql = mysql_query($insertar);

  if (!$sql) {

    echo "Algo salio mal";

  }
  
  mysql_close($conectar);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener datos desde una base de datos se utiliza la sentencia `SELECT` seguida de los datos a obtener y la tabla de donde provienen esos datos. Para tu ejemplo:

```html
<?php       
  $db="";
  $user="";
  $server="";
  $pass="";

  $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $db);
  if ($conexion->connect_errno) {
    echo "Falló al conectar. ".$conexion->connect_errno;
    exit();
  } 

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM tablat";
  foreach ($conexion->query($sql) as $dato) {
echo $dato['asunto'] . "<br>";
echo $dato['correo'] . "<br>";
echo $dato['mensaje'] . "<br>";
  }
?>
```

Las primeras líneas son tus datos de acceso a la base de datos. La extensión mysql está obsoleta en su lugar se utiliza mysqli. Luego de que se ejecuta el query; el resultado lo recorremos como un array donde los índices son los nombres de las columnas de tu tabla.

Comment: Ese script no me funciona en 000webhost y tengo la versión 7 php

Comment: ¿Qué error muestra?

Comment: No muestra nada, simplemente al enviar los datos no agrega nada en la base

Comment: Vamos por parte: para ingresar valores a la base de datos requieres de la sentencia INSERT INTO, para tu ejemplo: "INSERT INTO tablat(asunto,correo,mensaje) VALUES('$asunto', '$correo', '$mensaje')"; donde los valores 'asunto,correo,mensaje' son los titulo de cada columna de tu tabla.

Comment: No pues ya tengo todo el código formado, pero no funciona no sé si es 000webhost el que falla.

Comment: Dudo mucho que el problema lo tenga 000webhost, intenta en un servidor local como xampp o wampp

Comment: Me muestra lo siguiente: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli::mysqli_query()

Comment: Es interesante pues no utilicé mysqli_query(). Cambia ese método a $conecta->query($sql); donde $conecta es la conexión a la base de datos y $sql es la sentencia sql.

Answer (score 2):

`$db`,`$user`, `$server`, `$server` y `pass` son las credenciales para conectarte con la base de datos.

Llena esas variables con los datos correspondientes por ejemplo

```php
<?php
    
$db="MiBaseDeDatos";

$user="root";

$server="127.0.0.1";

$pass="1234";

$conecta = mysql_connect($server,$user,$pass);

                   mysql_select_db($db,$conecta);

 $asunto =$_POST['asunto'];
 $correo =$_POST['correo'];
 $mensaje =$_POST['mensaje'];

  $insertar = "INSERT INTO tablat VALUES('$asunto', '$correo', '$mensaje')";

  $sql = mysql_query($insertar);

  if (!$sql) {

    echo "Algo salio mal";

  }
  
  mysql_close($conectar);

?>
```

Si estás utilizando php 7 deberás usar `PDO` o `mysqli` ya que la clase `mysql` ya no la trae

Es más recomendable utilizar `mysqli` o `PDO`

```php
<?php
    
$db="MiBaseDeDatos";

$user="root";

$server="127.0.0.1";

$pass="1234";

$conecta= new mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$db);

// Revisar conexión
if ($conecta -> connect_errno) {
  echo "Conexión a MySql fallida: " . $conecta -> connect_error;
  exit();
}

 $asunto =$_POST['asunto'];
 $correo =$_POST['correo'];
 $mensaje =$_POST['mensaje'];

  $insertar = "INSERT INTO tablat VALUES('$asunto', '$correo', '$mensaje')";

  $sql = $conecta->mysqli_query($insertar);

  if (!$sql) {

    echo "Algo salio mal";

  }
  
  $conecta->close();
?>
```

Comment: muy cierto, me hice a la idea que su consulta era como conectarse a la base de datos al ver las variables vacías

Comment: no me funciona y eso que tengo php 7

Comment: que error te aparece?

Comment: Ninguno, simplemente cuando se rellenan los datos en el formulario y se envían en la base no aparece nada, no muestra nada ni errores